# google colab Incompatible shapes:node gradient_tape/mean_squared_error/BroadcastGradientArgs

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory, numpy-ndarray, vgg-net

I'm trying to run this code for a people counting algorithm.

```
model = build_model()

epoch = 50

print("total epoch ", epoch)

model.fit(x=train_dataset, shuffle=True, epochs=epoch)
save_model(model, MODEL_PATH, MODEL_JSON_PATH)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

After executing the command, I get this error message:

```
Incompatible shapes: [1,14,14,1] vs. [1,28,28,1]
     [[{{node gradient_tape/mean_squared_error/BroadcastGradientArgs}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_136758]
```